# SilverStripe 3.1 - Page creating & publishing from the FrontEnd

Tags: php, forms, silverstripe

for our company intranet, I created a page with a Form to create an E-Mailing from the frontend (Create a New E-Mailing Page).

The page should be Live after saving the form.
I did it like this, but I think I made a mistake somewhere. Because KW1, KW2, Date and SendDate are only visible on the frontend if I go to the backend and click publish again.

```
public static $allowed_actions = array(
    'MailingForm'
);

public function MailingForm() {
    $date = new DateField('EndDate', 'Gültig bis');
    $date->setConfig('showcalendar', true);

    $sendDate = new DateField('SendDate', 'Versanddatum');
    $sendDate->setConfig('showcalendar', true);

    $fields = new FieldList(
        new TextField('Title', 'Title'),
        new TextField('KW1', 'Start KW'),
        new TextField('KW2', 'End KW'),
        $date,
        $sendDate
    );

    $actions = new FieldList(
        new FormAction('createMailing', 'Erstellen')
    );

    //$validator = new RequiredFields('Title');

    return new Form($this, 'MailingForm', $fields, $actions);//, $validator);
}   

public function createMailing($data, $form) {
    $member = Member::currentUser();
    $filter = new URLSegmentFilter();

    $page = new Mailing();
    $form->saveInto($page);
    $page->PublisherID = $member->ID;
    $page->AuthorID = $member->ID;
    $page->ParentID = $this->ID;
    $page->URLSegment = $filter->filter($page->Title);
    $page->writeToStage('Stage');
    $page->publish('Stage', 'Live');

    // EMAIL BEG
    $email = new Email();

    $email->setTo('mail@mail.de'); 
    $email->setFrom('intranet@mail.de'); 
    $email->setSubject('Neues E-Mailing für '.$this->Title); 

    $messageBody = "
        <p>Neues E-Mailing wurde angelegt und wartet auf Freischaltung</p>
        <p><strong>Name:</strong> {$data['Title']}</p>
        <p><strong>KWs:</strong> {$data['KW1']} - {$data['KW2']}</p>
        <p><strong>Gültig bis:</strong> {$data['EndDate']}</p>
        <p><strong>Versanddatum:</strong> {$data['SendDate']}</p>
    "; 
    $email->setBody($messageBody); 
    $email->send();
    // EMAIL END

    return $this->redirect($this->Parent()->URLSegment.'/'.$this->URLSegment.'/'.$page->URLSegment);

}
```

If I replace `$page->writeToStage('Stage');
        $page->publish('Stage', 'Live');` with `$page->write()` than the page isn't published if i add `$page->write()` to the other two than i receive this error

> Can't find [Title of Page]/[Page ID] in stage Stage

Can someone help me here?

Thank you in advance

---

**To break down the problem again**

If I publish the Page with

```
$page->write();
$page->writeToStage('Stage');
$page->publish('Stage', 'Live');
```

than all data is submitted correctly but I receive the following error http://www.picbutler.de/bild/301819/erroroirpt.jpg and the page is only saved as live version. In the backend the page is than marked as "deleted from draft". **So I think this is the right direction.**

If I publish the Page with

```
$page->writeToStage('Stage');
$page->publish('Stage', 'Live');
```

I receive no error, the submitted data appears in the backend BUT NOT in the published version. I have to publish the Page again in the backend to make the data visible in frontend.

So any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: does ->doPublish() help?

Comment: simply add after $page->publish(...) or only doPublish?

Comment: I would try `$page->write()` and then `$page->doPublish()` like @munomono said, `doPublish()` will fix your problem.

Comment: hi, okay I added write() and doPublish() and removed writeToStage() and publish().

After submitting I received this error http://www.picbutler.de/bild/301819/erroroirpt.jpg

Comment: try replace write with writeToStage and then doPublish

Comment: no error but I also have to publish it again from the backend

Comment: guess $form->saveInto($page); does not do the trick. try push the values from the form as you do with PublischerID, AuthorID, ParentID etc. probable somebody more knowledgeable can explain why.

Comment: Thx for the try. But it also doesn't work. I still have to publish it again. Any other solutions?

Comment: Perhaps a variable is missing which is important to view the page correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, a million tries later i got it! :)
For everybody else who get stuck on this.

You just need to restore the live page to stage after writing

```
$page->write();
$page->doRestoreToStage();
```

That's all :)

Comment: instead of just down voting the answer, it would be usefull to tell me why in the comments. is there a mistake in code?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution!

Answer (score 2):

### Many many thanks for your two lines of codes

$page->write();

### $page->doRestoreToStage();

I have been struggling with SiteTree table for a last few days,trying to write a new record to this table.

One important point is never use SiteTree class directly otherwise it won't work

eg $mySiteTree = new SiteTree();  (Bad)

Create a new page extends SiteTree() , say, Mypage

```
$mypage = new Mypage();
$mypage->Title = 'My Page';
$mypage->URLSegment = 'testing';
$mypage->ShowInMenus = '1';
$mypage->Version = '1';
$mypage->ParentID = '24';
$mypage->write();
$mypage->doRestoreToStage();
```

Enjoy!!!!