# How do I programatically add a new Page to Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to add pages to the Silverstripe Site tree using a background process that calls an external API.

I'm just trying to get the code to create a new Programme Page right. At the moment I have:

```
$mySiteTree = new SiteTree();
$mySiteTree->ClassName = "Programme";
$mySiteTree->URLSegment = $newurl;
$mySiteTree->URLSegment = 'testurl';
$mySiteTree->Title = 'testing title';
$mySiteTree->ShowInMenus = '1';
$mySiteTree->ParentID = '86';
$mySiteTree->write();
```

This doesn't seem to create any page. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong or what I could try to do to debug this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SilverStripe 3.1 - Page creating & publishing from the FrontEnd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671943/silverstripe-3-1-page-creating-publishing-from-the-frontend)

Comment: A similar question has just been asked a couple of days ago. Please checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671943/silverstripe-3-1-page-creating-publishing-from-the-frontend - I suggest this to be closed as duplicate

Comment: SiteTree, should be page. A good reference is the built in default records.. https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/3.1/code/model/SiteTree.php#L1419

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things missing from your code and a few things that need to be fixed:

- When creating the new page call `new Programme()` rather than `new
  SiteTree()`
- You should not set the `ClassName`, the above change will
  take care of this
- There is no need to set the `URLSegment`. Silverstripe will automatically do this based on the Title you set
- Make sure a page with ID 86 exists
- You need to call `->publish('Stage', 'Live')` and `->flushCache()`

The following code should work:

```
$mySiteTree = new Programme();
$mySiteTree->Title = 'testing title';
$mySiteTree->ShowInMenus = '1';
$mySiteTree->ParentID = '86';
$mySiteTree->write();
$mySiteTree->publish('Stage', 'Live');
$mySiteTree->flushCache();
```

Comment: Make sure you first change current Stage to "Stage". AFAIK the call to `$mySiteTree->write();` will otherwise write to Live as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the CMS Unit Tests. They're an excellent example of how to create pages and other records programmatically. [This one in particular should get you started.](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/3.1.0/tests/model/SiteTreeTest.php#L127)