# How to set & lock SiteTree in Silverstripe 4?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

We're working on a project where Silverstripe acts as headless CMS with a single API data point.

The content is all from non-SiteTree dataobjects & the API data point is the only SiteTree record we need.

What is the best way of making sure the API data point exists & it is the only SiteTree record on each `/dev/build`. We could then disable `PagesAdmin` in `LeftAndMain` so users couldn't edit/ break it.

I've [found code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671943/silverstripe-3-1-page-creating-publishing-from-the-frontend) which would look a bit like this for our case:

```
$api = new API/AccessPoint();
$api->Title = 'API';
$api->URLSegment = 'home';
$api->ShowInMenus = '1';
$api->Version = '1';
$api->ParentID = '0';
$api->write();
$api->doRestoreToStage();
```

But I'm not sure of the correct approach for making sure that a `dev\build` removes all the other pages & creates 1 record of this page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`requireDefaultRecords()`](https://api.silverstripe.org/3/DataObject.html#method_requireDefaultRecords) in your DataObject to create records on a dev/build. You'll need to do some kind of check before creating a new one though, e.g.

```
public function requireDefaultRecords()
{
    parent::requireDefaultRecords();

    if (AccessPoint::get()->filter('URLSegment', 'home')->exists()) {
        return;
    }

    // create your new object here
}
```